# itertools combinations parse in nested np.array

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I tried to parse in an np.array or nested array to `itertools.combinations_with_replacement()` and ran into the dimension issue.

```
Current code only work for 1-d np.array:

X = np.array([1,2,3])  # Input

Xa = X.tolist()  # Convert to list
C = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(Xa, 2))
print(C) 

out= []
for j in range(len(C)):       
            out.append(np.prod(C[j]))

print(out)

# [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9]
```

But, for a 2-d or nested array with rows of similar dimension data, I have trouble getting it to work.

```
# Input:
X = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6],...])   # e.g., X.shape = (100, 3)


# Ideally, I would like to get an output for each row like below, 
# then multiply each tuple() within the list and compile into another np.array:

[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)] ---> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9]
[(4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 5), (5, 6), (6, 6)] ---> [16, 20, 24, 25, 30, 36]
[....]


# Final output:
out = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9], [16, 20, 24, 25, 30, 36]...])
```

I have tried `np.stack()` etc. and am still stuck :(

Answer (score 2):

Simply this?

```
X = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])

np.array([[np.prod(c) for c in combinations_with_replacement(row, 2)] for row in X])
```

or (faster)

```
np.prod([list(combinations_with_replacement(row, 2)) for row in X], axis=-1)
```

Comment: Thank you, Julien. This works! However, what if I need to run a for...loop to append combinations with different order? For example, the final-final results I am looking for will be the combinations of input np.array using "1", "2"...."d":

    for i in range(1, d+1):
        Xa = np.array([[np.prod(c) for c in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(row, i)] for row in X])

Comment: `np.hstack([[[np.prod(c) for c in combinations_with_replacement(row, i)] for row in X] for i in range(1, d+1)])` ?

Comment: yep. This solves the looping. I apologize for not being clearer. The problem takes multiple steps and I was hoping to figure the remaining out myself. Thanks much and now I know how the single-line for loop is so powerful!

Comment: PS: another way: `np.array([[np.prod(c) for i in range(1, d+1) for c in combinations_with_replacement(row, i)] for row in X ])`

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
# Dimension=(M, N)
X = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]])

# Use numpy broadcasting, Dimension=(M, N, N)
A = X[:, None, :] * X[:, :, None]

# Extract the upper triangle, Dimension=(M, N)
out = A[(slice(None), *np.triu_indices(A.shape[-1]))]

# More understandable?
# idx = np.triu_indices(A.shape[-1])
# out = A[:, idx[0], idx[1]]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
array([[  1,   2,   3,   4,   6,   9],
       [ 16,  20,  24,  25,  30,  36],
       [ 49,  56,  63,  64,  72,  81],
       [100, 110, 120, 121, 132, 144]])

>>> A
array([[[  1,   2,   3],
        [  2,   4,   6],
        [  3,   6,   9]],

       [[ 16,  20,  24],
        [ 20,  25,  30],
        [ 24,  30,  36]],

       [[ 49,  56,  63],
        [ 56,  64,  72],
        [ 63,  72,  81]],

       [[100, 110, 120],
        [110, 121, 132],
        [120, 132, 144]]])

>>> X
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

Comment: Nice! Faster than my solution.... +1

Comment: Although not as easily generalizable to combinations of more than 2 elements if OP cared?

Comment: I agree with you on this point. Probably `sliding_window_view` can be better.

Comment: Great. Thank you. This is a genius solution! Unfortunately though, i'm working on a problem with potential higher elements (i.e., greater than 2). I do appreciate your time and effort!